# How do I make my Mac Air running Lion recognize Chinese characters in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, osx-lion, chinese

I open an Excel document with Chinese characters and see the following.

[image]

How do I make my Mac Air running Lion recognize Chinese characters in Excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my answer on this page.

http://mymacslife.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-view-chinese-character-in-mac.html

1. Close any open Office applications.
2. In the Finder, open Microsoft Office 2011/Additional Tools/Microsoft Language Register, and then double-click Microsoft Language Register to open the application.
3. On the Select the language to enable for Microsoft Office pop-up menu, click Simplified Chinese or Traditional Chinese, and then click OK.